# ASP.NET MVC2 Custom Membership Provider w/ Data Provider Interface Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, custom-membershipprovider

I am creating a custom membership provider class library that defines a data provider interface for my web projects to implement.

I am having an issue creating an instance of the class that implements the interface.

I added a line in my web.config to pull the data provider type out, but it is looking for that type inside the membership library (but its defined in my web project).

```
public class MvcRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    private IDataProvider _dataProvider;

    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        var dataProviderType = config["dataProviderType"];
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[config["connectionStringName"]];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataProviderType))
        {
            var type = Type.GetType(dataProviderType, true, true);

            if (type != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString))
                _dataProvider = (IDataProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(type, ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

Web.config

```
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="WebTestRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="WebTestRoleProvider"
         applicationName="WebTest"
         type="MvcMembership.MvcRoleProvider, MvcMembership"
         dataProviderType="MyWebNameSpace.MyWebProject.DataProviderClassName"
         connectionStringName="TheConnectionStringName" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

The error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyWebNameSpace.MyWebProject.DataProviderClassName' from assembly 'MvcMembership, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Am I taking the right approach to this?  If I want generic custom membership library, shouldn't I be implementing the appropriate data provider in my web/data projects (in this example I am making one in web for testing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Assembly.CreateInstance like so:

Factory:

```
    public class DataProviderFactory
{
    public IDataProvider GetProvider(string assemblyName, string type, string connectionString)
    {
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(assemblyName));
        return (IDataProvider)assembly.CreateInstance(type, true, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[]{ connectionString }, null, null);
    }
}
```

RoleProvider:

```
 public class MvcRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    private IDataProvider _dataProvider;

    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        DataProviderFactory factory = new DataProviderFactory();
        _dataProvider = factory.GetProvider(config["dataProviderAssembly"], config["dataProviderType"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[config["connectionStringName"]]);

        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }
```

With the following settings in web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MvcRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MvcRoleProvider"
         applicationName="MyWebNameSpace"
         type="MvcMembership.MvcRoleProvider"
      dataProviderType="MyWebNameSpace.MyWebProject.DataProviderClassName"              dataProviderAssembly="EmailService.Web.EmailAdmin"
         connectionStringName="MyMembershipConnection" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```